# Is my Windows 10 genuine?

Tags: windows-10

To cut a long story short my father bought a new laptop without consulting me. I checked the laptop and it had KMSpico software on it. He paid the full price of the laptop and it "came" with Microsoft Office he probably told the people that work there that he needs it for work so he doesn't need to pay for it (i know it sounds really shady we are not from EU/US its piracy here everywhere, but i use GNU/Linux), but he paid the full price for the Windows 10 and got a sticker too but they put it on the bottom of the laptop which is strange because i always saw it on the front side besides the keyboard. I don't know if the KMSpico software was used to pirate MS Office or to pirate MS Windows 10 or maybe both. Here are some info's if you need more stuff just ask and ill post it. [Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A86U.png)
[slmgr.vbs /dli in Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8UeX.png)

Comment: Yes; Your father got scammed.  Your father paid for pirated software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools such as KMSpico work by running a fake KMS server (which always issues licenses without any checks), so they're only usable if your Windows system uses a KMS product key – you would see **`VOLUME_KMS channel`** in the license status output. Your screenshot instead shows an OEM license.

The same goes for Office: run `ospp.vbs /dstatus` and look for "VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel". This tool needs to be run from CLI:

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs" /dstatus
```

(Alternatively, for Office 2019, `slmgr.vbs /dlv 85dd8b5f-eaa4-4af3-a628-cce9e77c9a03` will display roughly the same information.)

---

On personal laptops, the VOLUME_KMS channel almost always means piracy, but on company-issued devices it's often legitimate. So if this was a corporate laptop and your OS *was* on the VOLUME_KMS channel, you would also need to run `slmgr.vbs /dlv` ([example output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/activation-troubleshoot-kms-general)) or `ospp.vbs /dstatus` to check what server is being used.

Comment: KMSpico isn't legitimate software. It's never required on a corporate device.

Comment: @Ramhound: Which is why I wrote "KMS" and not "KMSpico" there... One is an [official Microsoft licensing mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/configure-a-kms-host-computer-for-office), the other is a pirate tool that makes use of this mode.

Comment: @user1686 Thank you so much for the reply. Could you explain to me what does OEM_DM chanel mean ?